# Is this DE solvable?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

So this might be a very simple question and I've got a knot in my brain but I've been at this for days and don't see how I could solve this problem.

I'm trying to find the solution for both x(t) and y(t) in this equation:

$$a\frac{d}{dt} x(t)+ b \frac{d}{dt}y(t)=c x(t) $$

a,b,c and d are all greater than zero and real values.

The initial conditions x(0) and y(0) are known.

(The tags probably aren't correct)

For context:

I've stumbled upon this problem trying to find the solution for an electrical network consisting of two parallel capacitors with an ESR and another parallel resistor.

The original set of equations for this problem are derived from this
[circuit][1].

The current trough the single resistor is defined as:

$$i_{sc}=i_A+i_B$$

The current $i_A$ of capacitor A and B respectively are defined as:

$$\frac{d}{dt}u_{cA}(t)=\frac{1}{C_A}i_{A}(t)$$
$$\frac{d}{dt}u_{cB}(t)=\frac{1}{C_B}i_{B}(t)$$

with

$$i_A=\frac{u_{cA}-i_{sc}\cdot R_{sc}}{R_A}$$
$$i_B=\frac{u_{cB}-i_{sc}\cdot R_{sc}}{R_B}$$

Using $i_A=C_A\cdot \frac{d}{dt}u_{cA}$ and $i_B=C_B\cdot \frac{d}{dt}u_{cB}$ in the equation for $i_{sc}$ I get:

$$ C_A\cdot \frac{d}{dt}u_{cA}=\frac{u_{cA}-(C_A\cdot \frac{d}{dt}u_{cA}+C_B\cdot \frac{d}{dt}u_{cB})\cdot R_{sc}}{R_A}$$

$$ \frac{d}{dt}u_{cA} \cdot C_A \cdot(R_A +R_{sc}) =u_{cA}-C_B\cdot \frac{d}{dt}u_{cB}\cdot R_{sc}$$

Based on this equation I get the simplified version with $x=u_{cA}$ and $y=u_cB$:

$$a\frac{d}{dt} x(t)+ b \frac{d}{dt}y(t)=c x(t) $$
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9F7eB.png

I hope this helps!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: If they were coupled (in two different lines) you could take a matrix exponential and present that as a "closed form". There's no reason why this would be a simple question, since the form you leave it in is very general

Comment: Suppose $a\neq 0$. Then $x'-\frac{c}{a}x=\frac{d}{a}y-\frac{b}{a}y'$. This equation can be solved in integrals for $x(t)$ if we set $y(t)$. So, we can set $y(t)$ to any differentiable function corresponding to initial conditions, then integrate for $x$.

Comment: If you have only one equation and two unknows, you cannot solve it for the two unknons. The best that you can expect is a relationship between the two unknowns. The trouble comes from the incomplete system of equations that you got from the model. Another independant equation is missing. It's up to you to find it. As the question is written this is not yet a consistant mathematical problem.

Answer (score 1):

At begining your system of equations is consistent : Five unknowns $i_{sc}$ , $i_A$ , $i_B$ , $u_{cA}$ , $u_{cB}$ , $ $ and five equations :
$$\begin{cases}
i_{sc}=i_A+i_B \\
\frac{d}{dt}u_{cA}(t)=\frac{1}{C_A}i_{A}(t)\\
\frac{d}{dt}u_{cB}(t)=\frac{1}{C_B}i_{B}(t)\\
i_A=\frac{u_{cA}-i_{sc}\cdot R_{sc}}{R_A}\\
i_B=\frac{u_{cB}-i_{sc}\cdot R_{sc}}{R_B}
\end{cases}$$
Note : I didn't check if the equations are correct even if it seems at first sight that they are some sign mistakes with regard to the direction of currents drawn on the shematic of the circuit. Since this isn't matematical but modelisation I will not discuss this in my answer. The above system of equations is taken as granted despite the doubt.

During your manipulations 3 unknows where eliminated as well as 4 equations instead of only 3 unfortunately.

It is easy to elimnate $i_{sc}$ and the first equation :
$$\begin{cases}
\frac{d}{dt}u_{cA}(t)=\frac{1}{C_A}i_{A}(t)\\
\frac{d}{dt}u_{cB}(t)=\frac{1}{C_B}i_{B}(t)\\
i_A=\frac{u_{cA}-(i_A+i_B)\cdot R_{sc}}{R_A}\\
i_B=\frac{u_{cB}-(i_A+i_B)\cdot R_{sc}}{R_B}
\end{cases}$$
Then $i_A$ and $i_B$ can be isolated from the two last equations.

$i_A=\frac{u_{cB}\left( 1+\frac{R_A}{R_{sc}} \right)-u_{cA}}{R_{A}\left( 1+\frac{R_A}{R_{sc}} \right)+R_{B}}\quad$ and $\quad i_B=\frac{u_{cA}\left( 1+\frac{R_B}{R_{sc}} \right)-u_{cB}}{R_{A}\left( 1+\frac{R_A}{R_{sc}} \right)+R_{B}}\quad$ that we eliminate in puting them in the two remaining equations :
$$\begin{cases}
\frac{d}{dt}u_{cA}(t)=\frac{1}{C_A}\frac{u_{cB}\left( 1+\frac{R_A}{R_{sc}} \right)-u_{cA}}{R_{A}\left( 1+\frac{R_A}{R_{sc}} \right)+R_{B}}\\
\frac{d}{dt}u_{cB}(t)=\frac{1}{C_B}\frac{u_{cA}\left( 1+\frac{R_B}{R_{sc}} \right)-u_{cB}}{R_{A}\left( 1+\frac{R_A}{R_{sc}} \right)+R_{B}}
\end{cases}$$

With simplified  notations :
$$\begin{cases}
\frac{d}{dt}x(t)=c_1(c_3\:y(t)-x(t))\\
\frac{d}{dt}y(t)=c_2(c_3\:x(t)-y(t))
\end{cases}$$

Now we have got a consistent system of two equations with two unknons $u_{cA}$ and $u_{cB}$.
Of course all this would be simpler with matrix calculus from the very start.

To continue I suppose that you have learned how to solve a system of several linear ODEs.

Answer (score 0):

With two unknowns and a single equation you get a relation between $x(t),y(t)$ that can be solved/plotted. One more equation is needed for solving them both.